# Template [Partial] Specialization for Function - Determination at Compile Time

Tags: c++

Is there a way to get the following feature to work?

```
enum Color { RED, GREEN, BLUE };

struct Red {
  int myVar { 1 };
};

struct Green {
    int myOtherVar { 2 };
};

struct Blue {
  int myLastVar { 3 };
};

template <typename T>
struct MyStruct {
  template <typename PassIn, Color color>
  void method(PassIn );
};

template <typename T>
template <typename PassIn, Color color>
void MyStruct<T>::method(PassIn passIn) {
  switch (color) {
    case RED:
      cout << passIn.myVar << " RED" << endl;
      break;
    case GREEN:
      cout << passIn.myLastVar << " BLUE" << endl;
      break;
    case BLUE:
      cout << passIn.myOtherVar << " GREEN" << endl;
      break;
  }
}

int main() {
  MyStruct<int> myStruct;
  Red red;
  Green green;
  Blue blue;
  myStruct.method<Red, RED>(red);
  myStruct.method<Green, GREEN>(green);
  myStruct.method<Blue, BLUE>(blue);
  return 0;
}
```

Essentially, I want that 'color' parameter to tell 'method' what type of structure the 'passIn' variable is (whether it has 'myVar', 'myOtherVar', or 'myLastVar'). Is there a way to to this?

Comment: This seems needlessly complex. Why not just have three separate overloads?

Comment: Do you mean: method(Red r); method(Green g); method(Blue g)?
What if later I decide to add a red variant (that doesn't extend Red, but has 'myVar')?

Comment: Then revise the design later when you actually need to extend it?

Comment: If I could, I would like to do that, but unfortunately I cannot.

Comment: Why do you need *another* parameter to determine what type it is? You already have the passed in type! It's `PassIn`. It's unclear what problem you're solving that just overloading wouldn't solve much cleaner.

Comment: In this case it's easy to overload, but what if I have many 'passIn' types (Red1, Red2, Red3, etc.)? Then it gets more complicated and I need to have a way to distinguish all of them - preferably using some sort of Enum.
I believe I cannot do something like the following due to partial specialization:
template <typename T>
template <typename PassIn&>
MyStruct<T>::method<Red, PassIn&>(PassIn& passIn) { ... }